# Apache Stopps Working after config update

Tags: apache, xampp

There is a massive problem with my XAMPP apache..... Basically I have set-up virtual hosts, and I tagged the file.

So after I update the httpd.conf file it all the sudden I can not run the apache again......

I saved a copy of  the file as httpd.conf.ORG and I played with the other one and I added this:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName aam.dev
    DocumentRoot"C:\xampp\projects\aam.dev"
</<VirtualHost >

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName int.tech
    DocumentRoot"C:\xampp\projects\int.tech"
</<VirtualHost >

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "C:\xampp\projects\aam.dev">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "C:\xampp\projects\int.tech">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also added the two domains on the windows host file but When I tried to restart the apache it isn't WORKING AT ALL>>>>> it just says

> attempting to start Apache service..

And when I go to either the access log or the error log nothing out of interest, final entries are as follow:

Access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2013:18:28:40 +0100] "GET /xampp/ssi.shtml HTTP/1.0" 200 6 "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2013:18:28:40 +0100] "GET /xampp/status.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3110 "http://int.tech/xampp/navi.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"
```

Error.log

```
[Fri Oct 18 18:29:38.212991 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3864:tid 260] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Oct 18 18:29:38.252994 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6308:tid 384] AH00430: Parent: Child process 3864 exited successfully.
```

From my Understanding it just stopped normally, that is when I stopped it before making any changing, but after it is not working.... Finally, when I do restart the orginal httpd file it works.

I am assuming something is wrong with my VH Config?

Thanks in advance

BTW I am running XAMP 1.8.3